# order preserving implies isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Let $M = (M, <)$ and $N = (N, <)$ be two dense totally ordered sets without endpoints.
>
> Let $F$ be the collection of order preserving maps between finite subsets of $M,N$ respectively.
>
> Then $F$ is a non-empty family of partial isomorphisms between $M$ and $N$ with the back-and-forth property.

It's clear that $F$ is non-empty and each member of $F$ is an injective map, but
how can I show it's onto?

Comment: The way I've seen this shown is using Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games. Sadly I don't recall enough detail to answer, but it should give you search terms...

Comment: You can show that, if $f\in F$ and $x\in M$, there exists $g\in F$ such that $f\subseteq g$ and $x$ is in the domain of $g$; likewise, if $f\in F$ and $y\in N$, there exists $g\in F$ such that $f\subseteq g$ and $y$ is in the range of $g$. If $M$ and $N$ are **countable**, you can use that to construct a chain in $F$ whose union is an isomorphism from $M$ to $N$.

Comment: @James: What are you trying to show that a member of $F$ iss onto? Onto what set?

Comment: @bof, Ok but first, as the question indicates, I have to show $F$ is a non-empty family of partial isomorphisms between $M$ and $N$!!

Comment: I think it would help if you would just **define what you mean by** (a) an order preserving map between finite subsets of $M$ and $N$ and (b) a (finite) partial isomorphism between $M$ and $N$. To me, they are the same thing. Evidently your definitions differ, but I can't guess what they are.

Comment: If your difficulty is showing that $F$ is nonempty, just observe that $\emptyset\in F$. Or, if you don't like the empty function, choose any $a\in M$ and any $b\in N$ and let $f=\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$

Comment: @james: A "partial isomorphism" just means an injection defined over only part of $M$. I would review the definition of "partial isomorphism" to make sure you're understanding it.

Comment: @bof, Thanks the definitions are the same. so things are cleared

Comment: @bof However, I am interested in how to construct the isomorphism you have mentioned and satisfy an extar propery let us say if $a_1 < a_2$ in $A$ and $b_1 < b_2$ in $B$  with $a_i$ goes to $b_i$

Answer (score 1):

The crucial notion to define here is:

> map between finite subsets of $M,N$, respectively.

It would seem that you interpreted this as:

> $f: M_0\to N_0, \quad M_0\in \mathcal P^{<\omega}(M), ~N_0\in\mathcal P^{<\omega}(N)$

where $\mathcal P^{<\omega}(X)$ is the set of finite subsets of $X$ -- which is a very natural thing to do. Now, given such an $f:M_0\to N_0$, we can "extend" it to $f':M_0\to N_1$ with $N_0\subsetneq N_1$, and $f'$ wouldn't be onto.

So it seems that "between" in "map between [...]" includes a hidden/omitted surjectivity assumption -- i.e., the intended definition is:

> $f: M_0\to N_0, \quad M_0\in \mathcal P^{<\omega}(M),~ N_0\in\mathcal P^{<\omega}(N),~ f[M_0]= N_0$

Now if we add the "order-preserving" assumption on $f$ (that is to say, $f \in F$), it readily follows that $f$ is an order isomorphism.

---

Alternatively, one could drop the surjectivity condition for a "partial isomorphism from $M$ to $N$", but to me this definition means "an isomorphism between subsets of $M$ and $N$".